# YouTube video with custom start and end times not working on iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, safari, video, google-chrome, youtube

The following YouTube URL is not working as expected in Safari and Chrome on my iPhone 7:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/4NZycutQrUw?start=1523&end=2171&autoplay=1&controls=1

The video plays fine, but the start and end times are ignored. Has something changed that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/336928/edit) the question and specify the version of iOS running on your iPhone. Also specify whether this use to work as expected previously and whether you have the YouTube app for iOS installed.

Comment: On my iPhone 8; iOS 11.4.1 - this link works on both Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox Focus, however, does not honor the start/end times specified. Firefox Focus has stringent ad-blocker functionality and browsing privacy. Are you running any sort of VPN or ad-blocking software on your iPhone 7 that could be interfering?

Comment: iPhone 7 11.4.1 (15G77) - the start time works but the end time does not, it just plays to the end of the file...it used to work and now does not...I do not have the YouTube app, it's just using a browser window...

Comment: it works just fine on MacBook with Firefox.